# I got a garbled message in arduino while sending data from app (using flutter) to ESP8266

Tags: flutter, arduino, esp8266

The problem which I'm facing is that sending data from my phone to the ESP8266 is garbled... (I use NodeMCU's Amica)
I am using a package in Flutter which uses the WebSocket principle.
When I start the app, it connects fine. I get messages for a WebSocket handshake just fine, so I complete the handshake just fine. But when I send data from my Flutter app, it doesn't seem to work...

The code I have in Flutter:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';

var ip = 'ws://192.168.1.53:5555';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'WebSocket Demo';
    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: MyHomePage(
        title: title,
        channel: IOWebSocketChannel.connect(ip),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final WebSocketChannel channel;

  MyHomePage({Key key, @required this.title, @required this.channel})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Form(
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Send a message'),
              ),
            ),
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: widget.channel.stream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24.0),
                  child: Text(snapshot.hasData ? '${snapshot.data}' : ''),
                );
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _sendMessage,
        tooltip: 'Send message',
        child: Icon(Icons.send),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  void _sendMessage() {
    if (_controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      widget.channel.sink.add(_controller.text);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.channel.sink.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

I got this code from "https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/web-sockets".
This is just to test if it would work, the real coding will be later...
I changed the IP, and that's it.

In Arduino the code is this:

```
String Version = "===================================\r\n===================================\r\n===================================\r\n    [NAMEHERE] v1.0\r\nBugs to fix:\r\n o N/A\r\n===================================\r\n===================================\r\n===================================\r\n";

bool keySent = true;
String Key;

char ThrowAway;

String StringSlice;
String HexToBinary;
int HexToNumber;
String EncodedKey = "";
int Count = 0;

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <Hash.h>
#include <rBase64.h>

WiFiServer wifiServer(5555);

const char* ssid = "[NAME]";
const char* password = "[PASSWORD]";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println(Version);
 
  IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 53);
  IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 1, 1);
  IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);
  WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet);
 
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting ...");
  }
  Serial.print("Connected to WiFi. IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  wifiServer.begin();
 
}

void loop() {
WiFiClient client = wifiServer.available();
  if(client) {
    while(client.connected()) {
      while(client.available() > 0) {
        char c = client.read();
       
        //Reading key if applicable
        Serial.write(c);
        if(c == 'k') {
          c = client.read();
          Serial.write(c);
          if(c == 'e') {
            c = client.read();
            Serial.write(c);
            if(c == 'y') {
              c = client.read();
              Serial.write(c);
              if(c == ':') {
                c = client.read();
                Serial.write(c);
                c = client.read();
                while(c != '=') {
                  Serial.write(c);
                  Key = Key + c;
                  c = client.read();
                }
                while(c == '=') {
                  Serial.write(c);
                  Key = Key + c;
                  c = client.read();
                }
               
                Serial.print(c);
                calculateKey();
                keySent = false;
               
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if(keySent == false) {
        Serial.println("SENT:");
       
        Serial.write("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\nUpgrade: websocket\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nSec-WebSocket-Accept: ");
        client.write("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\nUpgrade: websocket\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nSec-WebSocket-Accept: ");
        Serial.println(Key);
        client.print(Key);
        client.write("\r\n\r\n");
       
        keySent = true;
      }
     
      delay(10);
    }
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("Client disconnected");
    Serial.println("###################");
    Key = "";
    EncodedKey = "";
    Count = 0;
  }
}


void calculateKey(){
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Calculating new key...");
 
  Key = Key + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
  Serial.print("Concatenating that with certain string: ");
  Serial.println(Key);

  Key = sha1(Key);
  Serial.print("Sha1 hash applied to key: ");
  Serial.println(Key);
 
  hexToBase64();
  Serial.print("And encoded in base64: ");
  Key = EncodedKey;
  Serial.println(Key);
  Serial.println();
}

String binaryToBase64(String x) {
 
  if(x == "000000")
    return "A";
  else if(x == "000001")
    return "B";
  else if(x == "000010")
    return "C";
  else if(x == "000011")
    return "D";
  else if(x == "000100")
    return "E";
  else if(x == "000101")
    return "F";
  else if(x == "000110")
    return "G";
  else if(x == "000111")
    return "H";
  else if(x == "001000")
    return "I";
  else if(x == "001001")
    return "J";
  else if(x == "001010")
    return "K";
  else if(x == "001011")
    return "L";
  else if(x == "001100")
    return "M";
  else if(x == "001101")
    return "N";
  else if(x == "001110")
    return "O";
  else if(x == "001111")
    return "P";
   
  else if(x == "010000")
    return "Q";
  else if(x == "010001")
    return "R";
  else if(x == "010010")
    return "S";
  else if(x == "010011")
    return "T";
  else if(x == "010100")
    return "U";
  else if(x == "010101")
    return "V";
  else if(x == "010110")
    return "W";
  else if(x == "010111")
    return "X";
  else if(x == "011000")
    return "Y";
  else if(x == "011001")
    return "Z";
  else if(x == "011010")
    return "a";
  else if(x == "011011")
    return "b";
  else if(x == "011100")
    return "c";
  else if(x == "011101")
    return "d";
  else if(x == "011110")
    return "e";
  else if(x == "011111")
    return "f";
 
  else if(x == "100000")
    return "g";
  else if(x == "100001")
    return "h";
  else if(x == "100010")
    return "i";
  else if(x == "100011")
    return "j";
  else if(x == "100100")
    return "k";
  else if(x == "100101")
    return "l";
  else if(x == "100110")
    return "m";
  else if(x == "100111")
    return "n";
  else if(x == "101000")
    return "o";
  else if(x == "101001")
    return "p";
  else if(x == "101010")
    return "q";
  else if(x == "101011")
    return "r";
  else if(x == "101100")
    return "s";
  else if(x == "101101")
    return "t";
  else if(x == "101110")
    return "u";
  else if(x == "101111")
    return "v";
   
  else if(x == "110000")
    return "w";
  else if(x == "110001")
    return "x";
  else if(x == "110010")
    return "y";
  else if(x == "110011")
    return "z";
  else if(x == "110100")
    return "0";
  else if(x == "110101")
    return "1";
  else if(x == "110110")
    return "2";
  else if(x == "110111")
    return "3";
  else if(x == "111000")
    return "4";
  else if(x == "111001")
    return "5";
  else if(x == "111010")
    return "6";
  else if(x == "111011")
    return "7";
  else if(x == "111100")
    return "8";
  else if(x == "111101")
    return "9";
  else if(x == "111110")
    return "+";
  else if(x == "111111")
    return "/";

}

void hexToBase64() {
WiFiClient client = wifiServer.available();
 
  for(;;) {
    StringSlice = Key.substring(Count,Count+1);
    Serial.print(StringSlice);
    if(StringSlice == "0")
      HexToBinary = "0000";
    else if(StringSlice == "1")
      HexToBinary = "0001";
    else if(StringSlice == "2")
      HexToBinary = "0010";
    else if(StringSlice == "3")
      HexToBinary = "0011";
    else if(StringSlice == "4")
      HexToBinary = "0100";
    else if(StringSlice == "5")
      HexToBinary = "0101";
    else if(StringSlice == "6")
      HexToBinary = "0110";
    else if(StringSlice == "7")
      HexToBinary = "0111";
    else if(StringSlice == "8")
      HexToBinary = "1000";
    else if(StringSlice == "9")
      HexToBinary = "1001";
    else if(StringSlice == "a")
      HexToBinary = "1010";
    else if(StringSlice == "b")
      HexToBinary = "1011";
    else if(StringSlice == "c")
      HexToBinary = "1100";
    else if(StringSlice == "d")
      HexToBinary = "1101";
    else if(StringSlice == "e")
      HexToBinary = "1110";
    else if(StringSlice == "f")
      HexToBinary = "1111";
    else
      break;
    Serial.print(" = ");
    Serial.println(HexToBinary);
    Count++;

   
    StringSlice = Key.substring(Count,Count+1);
   
    if(StringSlice == "0" || StringSlice == "1" || StringSlice == "2" || StringSlice == "3")
      HexToBinary = HexToBinary + "00";
    else if(StringSlice == "4" || StringSlice == "5" || StringSlice == "6" || StringSlice == "7")
      HexToBinary = HexToBinary + "01";
    else if(StringSlice == "8" || StringSlice == "9" || StringSlice == "a" || StringSlice == "b")
      HexToBinary = HexToBinary + "10";
    else if(StringSlice == "c" || StringSlice == "d" || StringSlice == "e" || StringSlice == "f")
      HexToBinary = HexToBinary + "11";
    else {
      HexToBinary = HexToBinary + "00";
      EncodedKey = EncodedKey + binaryToBase64(HexToBinary);
      EncodedKey = EncodedKey + "=";
     
      break;
    }

    EncodedKey = EncodedKey + binaryToBase64(HexToBinary);
   
   
    StringSlice = Key.substring(Count,Count+1);
   
    HexToBinary = "";
    if(StringSlice == "0" || StringSlice == "4" || StringSlice == "8" || StringSlice == "c")
      HexToBinary = "00";
    else if(StringSlice == "1" || StringSlice == "5" || StringSlice == "9" || StringSlice == "d")
      HexToBinary = "01";
    else if(StringSlice == "2" || StringSlice == "6" || StringSlice == "a" || StringSlice == "e")
      HexToBinary = "10";
    else if(StringSlice == "3" || StringSlice == "7" || StringSlice == "b" || StringSlice == "f")
      HexToBinary = "11";
   
    Count++;


    StringSlice = Key.substring(Count,Count+1);
    Serial.print(StringSlice);
    if(StringSlice == "0")
      HexToBinary = HexToBinary + "0000";
    else if(StringSlice == "1")
      HexToBinary = HexToBinary + "0001";
    else if(StringSlice == "2")
      HexToBinary = HexToBinary + "0010";
    else if(StringSlice == "3")
      HexToBinary = HexToBinary + "0011";
    else if(StringSlice == "4")
      HexToBinary = HexToBinary + "0100";
    else if(StringSlice == "5")
      HexToBinary = HexToBinary + "0101";
    else if(StringSlice == "6")
      HexToBinary = HexToBinary + "0110";
    else if(StringSlice == "7")
      HexToBinary = HexToBinary + "0111";
    else if(StringSlice == "8")
      HexToBinary = HexToBinary + "1000";
    else if(StringSlice == "9")
      HexToBinary = HexToBinary + "1001";
    else if(StringSlice == "a")
      HexToBinary = HexToBinary + "1010";
    else if(StringSlice == "b")
      HexToBinary = HexToBinary + "1011";
    else if(StringSlice == "c")
      HexToBinary = HexToBinary + "1100";
    else if(StringSlice == "d")
      HexToBinary = HexToBinary + "1101";
    else if(StringSlice == "e")
      HexToBinary = HexToBinary + "1110";
    else if(StringSlice == "f")
      HexToBinary = HexToBinary + "1111";
    else {
      HexToBinary = HexToBinary + "0000";
      EncodedKey = EncodedKey + binaryToBase64(HexToBinary);
      EncodedKey = EncodedKey + "==";
     
      break;
    }
    Count++;

    EncodedKey = EncodedKey + binaryToBase64(HexToBinary);
   
  }
 
  Serial.println("#############################################");
  Serial.println(EncodedKey);
 
}
```

I'll be cleaning this code up later... The bulk of what matters is upwards...
I changed the names of some stuff, for the privacy of the people whom I do this for.

My log resembles something like this:

```
Flutter sends WebSocket key.
Key sent back by ESP...

Message from App:
⸮⸮uD⸮ZD⸮⸮⸮⸮□⸮⸮□⸮
```

I tried to send something like "Hello World" or "test"
Those weird characters are multiple messages by the way...

Just to verify, the key is right.
If I were to send a wrong key back, it would disconnect.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

I think it is something with the timings of which messages get sent or received.

If there is anything I need to add, please tell me.

Comment: Your question is too long. I think you are also making this whole thing complicated when you can easily communicate through MQTT or Firebase Realtime Database <- (Use listeners here). What are you trying to do in your project? Please tell me so I could help you.

Comment: looking at the value thats printing...check once ur code baud rate matches with serial montor's